# Is there a monitor that can achieve the resolution of an android smartphone?

Tags: multiple-monitors, android, resolution

The resolution of the screen of my smartphone is `720 x 1520 pixels`, and I like how everything is clear on my device such as when using YouTube and other apps, everything seems to be in HD. Now on my PC, the screen resolution is fuzzy and all text is blurry, and I kind of feel inadequate for it. Am not going to mention the resolution but are there screens out there capable of displaying better than my phone's screen because I would also like the same visual experience I get when I use my PC like on my phone.

Comment: You need a 4k monitor and a video card that supports it.

Comment: @Moab 4k at 24" isn't high enough resolution to actually match the OP's request.

Comment: OP is going to be sitting a fair bit further back from a phone tho - https://superuser.com/questions/990799/will-the-pixel-density-difference-be-visible-between-4k-and-2k-monitors-at-27-s/991823#991823 relevant answer I posted in the past

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - I hadn't actually taken that into consideration ;) I have a 55" 4k OLED TV [80 ppi] which I can't see a single pixel on at 8ft viewing distance, though I can  if I sit up closer & use it as a computer monitor. My Mac's 2x27" 2k screens I can see pixels, but not enough to really bother me. Our new M1 iMac is 4.5k on 24" [218 ppi] & that's very smooth.

Comment: `Now on my PC, the screen resolution is fuzzy` What have you done to get the screen to your PC? Have you forwarded the Android screen to your PC using some software or do you use an Android emulator? If a  resolution is fuzzy and all text is blurry then this usually a problem of the used program. Unfortunately your question does not contains any details about the used software (or hardware?)

Comment: A fussy video can also mean that your resolution is fine, but you simply need to increase the display setting on youtube using the cog icon. During the pendamic, Youtube has set the default to 480p. Even if your display has a higher resolution, it will look blurry. The video may also have 720p or 1080p that was not selected. Check that it has a higher resolution in the video before replacing any hardware.

Comment: 720x1520 pixels on a PC monitor is the resolution typical 25-30 years ago.  It isn't your screen that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually a very high resolution for a phone these days, but should be just about high enough to qualify as HiDPI or Retina.
For comparison, the iPhone 6 in 2014 had about that resolution, with a ppi of 320.

The numbers are a bit wooly, but 'Retina' resolution is considered to be about 320 ppi and higher. Some phones are now up to 480ppi.

A 24" 4k screen [3840x2160] is about 184 ppi. The current high-end Apple screens, the XDR [6k] & Studio [5k], reach 218. The current MacBook Pros are reaching 250 ppi.
The  Dell UltraSharp UP3218K reaches 280 ppi.

I don't know of anything yet that is higher.

From comments above, as you're viewing a screen from further away than a phone, this does in fact make 200 ppi very smooth from a couple of feet away.

Comment: Okay thanks, I really hope they would improve my visual experience. Is a video card a must? My computer has HDMI

Comment: HDMI is a connection type, it doesn't define what resolution the graphics can drive.

Comment: Okay so I make connection to card and then to monitor?

Comment: We don't know. You have given us absolutely no information to work with.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of monitors that have similar or greater resolutions to those common to phones. The main issue is pixel density, but that's not the only issue.

Because the resolution of a phone screen is squeezed into a very small screen, it gives you a very high pixel density. Also, because a phone is typically held closer to your eyeballs, that high pixel density is useful for giving you a crisp, clear picture on content that uses it properly.

However, your phone's stated resolution is actually quite low compared with the phones I've used. You're not looking at a high end phone or truly high resolution display. It's perfectly adequate, but not anything special.

Many monitors have higher numbers of pixels squeezed into their frames, but those frames are also much, much larger, so even though there are more pixels, the density is much, much lower. But this isn't a problem on its own because monitors are usually just over arms length away from our eyeballs, so a strict pixels-per-square-inch comparison is not very useful. Perhaps pixels per square inch at intended viewing distance is a better measure and could be assumed, but there aren't any numbers currently to measure or convey that.

Further, the shape of the pixels in the monitor's construction has an impact on perceived sharpness, and then the way the software is able to talk to the hardware in order to convey those images, and finally the resolution of the content itself, and it's clarity and precision, will all impact the quality of the image you perceive.

So, this is a deceptively complex issue, and the right answer is to learn the limits and capabilities of your various hardware, upgrade what you can, know the quality of your content and, if you care, use the higher quality content where possible, if it doesn't go beyond the hardware's ability.